# nodeJS jake file Hello World Program Not working

Tags: node.js, jake

I have a simple hello world jake file, which gives an error:

victors-macbook-pro:votefor Victor$ jake -f jakefile asynchronous

*(in /Users/Victor/Documents/workspace/votefor/votefor)
Error on line 1 of file [unknown]
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: desc*

victors-macbook-pro:votefor Victor$ cat jakefile

```
desc('This is an asynchronous task.');
task('asynchronous', [], function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("Yay, I'm asynchronous!");
          complete();
    }, 1000);
}, true);
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong ?

The code was copied and pasted from http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake

Comment: Sounds like you are executing the file in a wrong environment. How do you call your tasks? `jake [options] target (commands/options ...)`?

Comment: hi @SebastianG i have updated my question to show my actions take step by step. thanks!

Comment: Can you check if node is working properly. Maybe jake installation is broken. How did you install jake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute it like this

```
jake -f path_to_file.js asynchronous
```

Be sure to install it globally (I got `npm WARN prefer global jake@0.5.16 should be installed with -g`)

```
npm install jake -g
```

Comment: many thanks. i tried what you said, but to no avail. i've updated my question with all the commands i tried too